# Other Linker Flags Section is missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

when I try to set -ObjC in "Other Linker Flags" in Build Settings --> Linking
there is no "Other Linker Flags" section in "Linking."

Why it is hidden ?
Please help me to show it up, thanks in advance.

Comment: What *type* of Xcode target is it?  I expect it's one that doesn't involve linking, like a static library?

Comment: There is options, Basic and all, click all then you will see it.